# Is there a Miracast Client/Server for Mac or Windows?

Tags: android, screen-capture

I was wondering if anyone knows any Mac or Windows clients/servers that support the Miracast standard?

At my company we demo our applications very often via Video Conferences/Skype/Join.me/etc, so it would be grate if I could share the screen of my Android device via Miracast to my Mac or Win-PC.

Sharing to a TV that supports is not an option unfortunately.

I've seen a lot of devices that have HDMI output and support Miracast (i.e NetgearPTV3000) but I couldn't find any info related to this devices which notes that they would work with a Mac or Win workstation.

Comment: http://www.airserver.com/ may be what you need. (Haven't tested this myself)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Miracast client will be available for an upcoming update of Windows 8.

Mac however, no idea.